# Subir Archivos con Php y Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Soy nuevo con Ajax intento subir archivos a mi carpeta y almacenar la ruta en mi MySQL, estos son mis avances:

Tengo mi ventana modal, con la cual colocas los datos del archivo:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="../../phpcrud/create_documentos.php" method="POST" id="create_documentos_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="modal-body">


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="titulo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Titulo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo">
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="archivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Elejir Documento</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo"/>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">   
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Mi evento se llama create_documentos_form, y este es el codigo de mi.js

```
$("#create_documentos_modal").on('click', function() {
    $("#create_documentos_form")[0].reset();
    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
    $(".text-danger").remove();
    $(".message_create_documentos").html("");

    $("#create_documentos_form").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function()            
  {
        $(".text-danger").remove();
        var form = $(this);

        var titulo = $("#titulo").val();
        var file2 = document.getElementById("archivo");   //TENGO DUDA
        var archivo = file2.files[0];                     //TENGO DUDA

        if(titulo && archivo) 
        {
            $.ajax({
                url : form.attr('action'),
                type : form.attr('method'),
                data : form.serialize(),
                dataType : 'json',
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Reviso que en mi variable archivo contenga algo mediante un console.log()

[image: Consola]

Al parecer ahi todo esta bien esta el nombre de la imagen, tamaño etc, intento almacenarla en mi archivo Php de la siguiente manera:

```
 if($_POST) {
 $validator = array('success' => false, 'message_create_documentos' => array());

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];

$nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
$tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
$ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
$destino = "archivos/" . $nombre;

$sql = "INSERT INTO documentos (titulo,ruta) VALUES ('$titulo', '$destino')";
$query = $connect->query($sql);

if($query === TRUE) {
    $validator['success'] = true;
    $validator['message_create_documentos'] = "Agregado Exitosamente";
} else {
    $validator['success'] = false;
    $validator['message_create_documentos'] = "Error mientras agrega la información";
 }

$connect->close();
echo json_encode($validator);
}
```

En esta parte es en donde el registro se pierde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#create_documentos_form").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function(){
    $(".text-danger").remove();
    var form = $(this);

    var titulo = $("#titulo").val();
    var file2 = $('#archivo');   //Ya que utilizas jquery aprovechalo...
    var archivo = file2[0].files;       //el array pertenece al elemento

    if(titulo && archivo) 
    {

        // Crea un formData y lo envías
        var formData = new formData(form);
        formData.append('titulo',titulo);
        formData.append('archivo[]',archivo);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'url.php',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Ivan me has solucionado un gran problema

Comment: Esta respuesta tiene 2 errores. 1.- Es [`var formData = new FormData(form)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) (`F` mayuscula). 2.- Esta línea `formData.append('archivo[]',archivo);`, el nombre del campo debería ser sin corchetes (`[]`), de lo contrario se estará enviando un `array` de archivos en lugar de un solo archivo. Observaciones: si al crear el `formData` se pasa el formulario, entonces no ser necesario agregar los campos manualmente

Comment: si me acado de dar cuenta de ese problema @MarcosGallardo muchas gracias

Comment: Lo cambie pero me marca este error en consola: TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.

Comment: @Rastalovely, has encontrado el 3er error, la variable `form` es un `jQueryObject` y no un `HTMLFormElement`. La solución a ese error es esta: `var formData = new FormData(form[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

Una solución es usar la API [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) (`IE10+`).

Ejemplo:

```
$("#create_documentos_form").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
    $(".text-danger").remove();
    var form = $(this);

    var titulo = $("#titulo").val();
    var file2 = document.getElementById("archivo");
    var archivo = file2.files[0];

    if(titulo && archivo) {

        $.ajax({
          url : form.attr('action'),
          type : form.attr('method'),
          data : new FormData(form[0]), // <-- usamos `FormData`
          dataType : 'json',
          processData: false,  // <-- le indicamos a jQuery que no procese el `data`
          contentType: false // <-- le indicamos a jQuery no establecer el `contentType`
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "HTML/docAjax.php",
                    data: {
                       post1 = "Post1",
                       post2 = "Post2"                            

                     },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {

                    //aqui cachas lo que regresas con el archivo php
                   console.log(data);


                }

    });
```

Comment: Con esto lo pones en tu funcion y dependiendo lo que devuelvas en el php es lo que va recibir la funcion data un ejemplo seria.      $post1 = $_POST["post1"]; $ post2 = $_POST["post2"];    echo $post1." y ".$post2;

Comment: Gracias clemente estoy revisando...

Answer (score 0):

Buenas Dias, permiso y para agregar le que me Vaya mostrando el porcentaje en un div ? en otras palabras que mientras suba el archivo, muestre el porcentaje de subida y que pueda mostrar ese valor en porcentaje en un div que tiene **id="porcentaje"** y en un div que tiene **id="progress" style="width:porcentaje a mostrar;"**

no se si me di a entender.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container navbar">
        <h2>Subir Archivos de publicaciones</h2>
        <p>The .active class animates the progress bar:</p>
        <div class="form collapse navbar-collapse">

            <form action="" id="form-subirimg">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="cod"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Codigo de registro</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" id="subir" multiple required placeholder="Ingrese codigo para registrar">
                </div>

                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="progress" style="min-width: 5%;">
                        <div id="porcentaje"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" id="msm">

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span>Subir</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-rigth" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.js"></script>
```